# Table Cell containing subreport is missing borders and background color when exported to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, subreport

I have an SSRS report as seen below which has a column (the 3rd column in the picture) that contains a subreport.  When viewed from the web browser the 3rd column correctly shows the grey border and it respects the alternating row colors.

[image: Report with background color and border]

However, when I export it to PDF, the alternating row colors and the border are lost on cells where there are no rows in the subreport.

[image: Report missing background color and border]

The subreport is currently placed inside of rectangle that forms the cell and the rectangle is what sets the border and background color.
How can I configure my report so that it shows up correctly in both the web browser and PDF?

Answer (score 2):

I found a blog entry from Peter Morlion at coderwall.com entitled [Forcing a SSRS subreport to show](https://coderwall.com/p/meqrng/forcing-a-ssrs-subreport-to-show) which explains how if there are no rows in any datasets in the subreport then the subreport will not show.  I was able to take the first part of his solution to fix my issue.  Here is what I did:

1. I added a new Dataset to my subreport called "DummyDataSet"
2. I set the query for the new dataset to `SELECT ' ' AS Dummy`

Once I deployed the report everything worked as expected in both the web browser and the PDF export version.